# Change Canvas.ZIndex for Grid in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have this XAML-code:

```
<Grid x:Name="Sample" Canvas.ZIndex="20"...
```

How I can change ZIndex of this Grid using C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found out the answer.

Use for it:

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(obj, N);
```

obj is Grid (or another UIElement), N is ZIndex (Int32).